# Cakephp index is in app/webroot

Tags: php, cakephp

ive just added `ACL` permission to my newly created cake project. However when i try to access it to create `groups` and `users` i get the following message:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /Udlejning/app/webroot
```

This is the error message for just the index ie `localhost/Udlejning/`.

Can anyone tell me why it is redirecting me there and how i can fix it?

It is worth mentioning that i have the following rules in my Users controller:

```
  public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    // For CakePHP 2.0
    $this->Auth->allow('*');

    // For CakePHP 2.1 and up
    $this->Auth->allow();
}
```

And that my AppController looks like this:

```
   public function beforeFilter() {
    //Configure AuthComponent
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index');
}
```

**These are my redirect rules**

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Specs**

I am using Cake 2.4 and Linux mint

Comment: The mentioned htaccess file has nothing to do with your issue. The issue is most likely a server misconfiguration. You need to allow "AllowOverwrite" for one of your parent htaccess files or even better for your vhost setup. Otherwise (on some machines `AllowOverwrite None` is the default value), your htaccess files are not being processed and ignored - thus resulting in your error. Note: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using. And in this case also, what OS you are using.

Comment: @mark ive added cake version and Os to my question

Comment: Standard your main index.php file is in app/webroot so that is correct. It will get there with .htaccess files. So that is all normal. Your message seems to relate to a configuration error with ACL. For a test first try to give all permissions to all controllers via the app controller. Then you can start testing with limiting it. So first give all access public and then start refining if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set your auth->allow before you call the parent function

```
public function beforeFilter() {

 // For CakePHP 2.0
 $this->Auth->allow('*');

 // For CakePHP 2.1 and up
 $this->Auth->allow();

 parent::beforeFilter();

}
```

Comment: Sadly this had no effect.

Comment: let me know if it works, but on the 2nd thought, it shouldn't really matter where you call the parent beforeFilter function.

Comment: I dont think it has anything to do with the code at all, it has to be something missconfigured on the server side. Did you check AllowOverwrite None as Mark said?